# What information is stored in a context area in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I learnt that context area in oracle is a private memory space where information needed for processing SQL statements are stored. However, I didn't get anywhere knowledge about what information is stored there.

Comment: Just out of interest, where did you learn this? It seems a poor source of information which tells you a thing exists but can't tell you anything useful about it.

Comment: I saw it in Javapoint and later searched more to know about context area but didn't find much information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a default context named `'userenv'` which stores a great deal of information about the session. We can access the information using `sys_context()`. For instance, to get the database name...

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME') from dual;
```

All of the valid parameters are listed in [the SQL Reference for `sys_context` here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117).

Some very useful parameters are 'ACTION', 'MODULE' and 'CLIENT_INFO'. These fields are populated through [`dbms_application_info` calls](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dbms_application_info), which allows us to pass information between programs.

However, we can extend this capability further by defining out own context namespaces. This requires [the CREATE CONTEXT privilege](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5003.htm#SQLRF01202) (by default only available to DBA users). Programs write to and read from context using [`dbms_session` calls](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS054). With our own context namespace we can stash bespoke information in session memory. Fine-Grained Access control (row-level and column security) relies on this feature. So there's a lot more about contexts in [the Security Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/app_context.htm#DBSEG70071).

Comment: Thanks that is really very helpful.